# Function that takes another function inside

Tags: functions

Looking at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545113/function-of-a-function), I'm trying the following - 2 functions (r in vector format) using Theta { A, 2 } functions (sorry for the inconsistent names...).

```
ihat = {1, 0, 0}
jhat = {0, 1, 0}
khat = {0, 0, 1}
ThetaA[t_] := 0.2 Pi Cos[50 t];
Theta2[t_] := 0.2 Pi Sin[50 t - Pi/3];
L1 = L2 = 5.0;
rAO[ThetaA_, t_] := L1 Sin[ThetaA[t]] ihat + L1 Cos[ThetaA[t]] jhat
rBA[t_] := (L2 Sin[Theta2[t]] + rAO[[1]]) ihat 
         + (L2 Cos[Theta2[t]] + rAO[[2]]) jhat
```

which gives me the following errors:

[image]

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my functions. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like maybe r_(A/O) and r_(B/A) had values before you tried to turn it into a function.

Comment: Yes, there is a glaring inconsistency. The penultimate line defines a function of two parameters, and yet you call this function in the last line without reference to any parameter.

Comment: Please don't post images of code you would like others to evaluate. Reduce your question to a minimal example, and then write the code of that in your post.

Comment: @David I agree with minimality. Why is image bad? I thought it'd better when it comes to semi-graphical programming tool like Mathematica

Comment: Not as extreme as @David's position, but: you're asking us for help to debug your code. Please do bother to take time to post something, anything, that can be easily copied into *Mathematica* in your question. The image only serves as an additional diagnostic, and other than that, it's not something we can debug...

Comment: @J. M. Oh that makes complete sense. I'll do that from next time (not for this question since I've already marked as solved).

Comment: Just so that my position is glaringly clear: a screenshot is nice to have; copyable code is **need** to have.

Comment: To be clear, here's the [relevant discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/97/52) on meta. Also, here's a list of of other [discussions to keep in mind](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/135/52).

Comment: I copied and formatted your code as the picture of it would not help anyone who happens to run across it later. In the process, I removed all of the Mathematica markup as it would have made the code very difficult to read.

Comment: @rcollyer oh, I should have copied my code myself if I knew someone would do that...thanks!

Comment: @rcollyer In the process you've removed the reason for the error — the use of `O`, a protected symbol, as a subscript...

Comment: @R.M argh! I should have read the solution itself. I'll fix it this afternoon.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because you're using [`O`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/O.html), which is a built-in function to represent a term of a particular order. This has the attribute `Protected`, which prevents you from assigning any definition to it.

```
Attributes@O
Out[1]= {Protected, ReadProtected}
```

However, to answer the question in your title, here are a few simple ways in which you can use a function inside another function:

#### 1: Simply call the function!

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[x_] := Sin[f[x]]
```

[image]

#### 2: Use a `Module`

```
g[x_] := Module[{f},
  f[y_] := y^2; Sin[f[x]]
  ]
```

[image]

#### 3: Pass the symbol for the function

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[func_Symbol, x_] := Sin[func[x]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think `Clear` did the work for me (now have another error), and it makes me realize that  capital 'O' is reserved by Mathematica. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @IsaacSaito Yes, that's a built in function. I've added a link to the documentation. I was a bit hesitant at first, because I wasn't sure if it was `o` or `O`, which is where a copyable code would've helped :)

Comment: We probably should have a list of functions like `D[]`, `N[]`, and `O[]` stashed here somewhere... ;)

Comment: @J.M. or maybe just remind people not to use capital letters to name variables and functions... a pretty useful lesson for those new to Mathematica.